# Can someone explain how Laravel shares variables with view?

Tags: php

In Laravel controller function you can return view with array of variables you like to share with the current view. Something like this:

```
public function index() {
  return view('index')->with(['name' => 'John doe']);
}
```

Then you can use the `name` inside the `with()` function as `$name` in your view.

Can someone explain how it been done please? I would like to do something similar by myself.

Answer (score 2):

We can pass individual pieces of data to the view using the 'with' method.

When passing information in this manner, the data should be an array with key / value pairs. Inside your view, we can then access each value using its corresponding key, such as

```
<?php echo $key; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel include the view file inside a function which makes all defining variables scope within a function.

Just before including files laravel calls PHP's builtin function **extract(array)** which declare all the variable in the scope.

`extract` create variables out of array making `key` as variable name and `value` as variable value.